# Improving UIPAB navigation in web.config file

Tags: asp.net, xml, navigation, web-config

I am doing some work on a company legacy project and there is a rather large section of the web.config file which I would like to clean up. The section in question is the view navigation which uses UIPAB. There are about 51 different pages which causes 2,200 lines of code, out of the 2,500 line web.config file. It took me a fair amount of time to figure out why there was so much duplication.

From how I've come to understand it, each page is listed as a view, and then each view must have all visit-able links detailed below in a node for that view.

I can understand why there is a  for each page, but it makes no sense (in my case) for each of the 's to have their own node full of duplicated links. In my case the navigation is not going to be changing between the different pages, so why cant I just list the values in  once and be done with it.

```
<views>
<view name="section1" type="section1/home.aspx" controller="section1controller" />
<view name="section1one" type="section1/one.aspx" controller="section1controller" />
<view name="section1two" type="section1/two.aspx" controller="section1controller" />
<view name="section2" type="section2/home.aspx" controller="section2controller" />
<view name="section2one" type="section2/one.aspx" controller="section2controller" />
<view name="section2two" type="section2/two.aspx" controller="section2controller" />
</views>
<node view="section1">
<navigateTo navigateValue="section1" view="section1" />
<navigateTo navigateValue="section1one" view="section1one" />
<navigateTo navigateValue="section1two" view="section1two" />
<navigateTo navigateValue="section2" view="section2" />
<navigateTo navigateValue="section2one" view="section2one" />
<navigateTo navigateValue="section2two" view="section2two" />
</node>
<repeat above 5 more times for each other view>
```

Is there anyway I can cut this down to more reasonable sizes?

Answer (score 0):

So after weeks of research and effort I finally found what I was looking for. UIPAB has sharedTransitions. It was in a document called [UIPAB.pdf](http://read.pudn.com/downloads11/sourcecode/windows/44459/UIPAB.pdf) which I found with a google search. It was page 67 of 134 which is what allowed me to do this. Currently I have not figured out how to remove the nodes and the single entry thats needed inside. This answer will help others who are having the same issue, but is not a final solution yet. If I solve (or someone helps solve) this part then I will update the answer.

```
<views>
   <view name="section1" type="section1/home.aspx" controller="section1controller" />
   <view name="section1one" type="section1/one.aspx" controller="section1controller" />
   <view name="section1two" type="section1/two.aspx" controller="section1controller" />
   <view name="section2" type="section2/home.aspx" controller="section2controller" />
   <view name="section2one" type="section2/one.aspx" controller="section2controller" />
   <view name="section2two" type="section2/two.aspx" controller="section2controller" />
</views>
<navigationGraph iViewManager="" name="" state="" statePersist="" startView="" cacheExpirationMode="" cacheExpirationInterval="">
<sharedTansitions>
   <sharedTansition navigateValue="section1" navigateTo="section1" />
   <sharedTansition navigateValue="section1one" navigateTo="section1one" />
   <sharedTansition navigateValue="section1two" navigateTo="section1two" />
   <sharedTansition navigateValue="section2" navigateTo="section2" />
   <sharedTansition navigateValue="section2one" navigateTo="section2one" />
</sharedTransitions>
<node view="section1"><navigateTo navigateValue="section2two" view="section2two" /></node>
<node view="section1one"><navigateTo navigateValue="section2two" view="section2two" /></node>
<node view="section1two"><navigateTo navigateValue="section2two" view="section2two" /></node>
<node view="section2"><navigateTo navigateValue="section2two" view="section2two" /></node>
<node view="section2one"><navigateTo navigateValue="section2two" view="section2two" /></node>
<node view="section2two"><navigateTo navigateValue="section2two" view="section2two" /></node>
</navigationGraph>
```

This allows me to reduce the navigation down from each page needing a link to every other page, to each page needs a single link to some page (Im using one thats not included in the sharedTransitions). So its now about 5 lines (one in views, 1 in sharedTransitions, and 3 in node) instead of pages*pages. Its not perfect yet because of the nodes still being present, but its a great step forward.